# First day of the month retrieval from SQL table with existing dates

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database that collects data called `PARTS`, and one column is called `TM_DLVRY`. `TM_DLVRY` stores all the dates that things were delivered in this format: `MM/DD/YYYY`. I need retrieve the first day of each month for deliveries because I am making graphs.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT TM_DLVRY
FROM PARTS
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(Year(TM_DLVRY), Month(TM_DLVRY), 1) ;
```

I read all the other questions I could find that were similar to this one, but none of them got me what I was going for.

I am not used to coding SQL in SQL Developer, and all of this is coming from MS Access. Before, in MS Access I could just use DateSerial( , , 1) to get this, but now I have to rewrite everything for SQL Developer and I'm having a slow start. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TM_DLVRY
FROM PARTS
WHERE TM_DLVRY.Day=1;
```

or

```
SELECT TM_DLVRY
FROM PARTS
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM TM_DLVRY)=1;
```

Is this what your looking for? The WHERE in SQL should be an equivalence statement of some kind.

Comment: yes, that's what I want but I tried it and it won't work. I don't know how to tell SQL that it needs to look for the day in the "timestamp" format it's in.

Comment: maybe DAYOFMONTH() instead

Comment: Is is a string value or is it a true date?

Comment: it is a true date i believe

Comment: If it's a string, WHERE RIGHT(LEFT(TM_DLVRY,5),1)='1'

Comment: I suspect you want to do something as in bf2020's answer. I'm not sure if year() and month() are valid functions on Oracle. If not then I think we're unclear about what your query is supposed to return.

Comment: I would like my query to return each timestamp that was generated on the first day of each month.

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE for PARTS?

Comment: Oh, I'm out of ideas unfortunately. Seems like either DAY() or DAYOFMONTH() should be working... weird

Comment: Is what you've tried having an error or just not returning anything?

Comment: it was returning an error. but i'm going to try to recreate the function dateserial from access in oracle's sql

Comment: Try this real quick... up top

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert TM_DLVRY to the first day of the month, then you need to move DATEFROMPARTS up into the select statement.  But you actually don't even really need that.

You can also do some math/counting in that statement, like maybe try:

```
SELECT to_char(TM_DLVRY,'yyyy') as Year, to_char(TM_DLVRY,'mm') as month, COUNT(TM_DLVRY) as monthly count
FROM PARTS
GROUP BY to_char(TM_DLVRY,'yyyy'), to_char(TM_DLVRY,'mm');
```

Comment: Oracle is saying that month and day are not valid